# What is a Sulphurous Word™?

Tags: knowledge, word-property

*This puzzle is based on the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee).*

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Sulphurous Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Sulphurous Words™ | Not Sulphurous Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| POGONIP | FROST |
| OHIO | MASSACHUSETTS |
| TATTOO | PIERCING |
| SLOGAN | MOTTO |
| MUSTANG | TARPAN |
| SAFARI | VOYAGE |
| VAMPIRE | GHOUL |
| SOMA | ICHOR |
| GLAMOUR | FASHION |
| BERIBERI | KWASHIORKOR |

CSV version:

```
pogonip,frost
Ohio,Massachusetts
tattoo,piercing
slogan,motto
mustang,tarpan
safari,voyage
vampire,ghoul
soma,ichor
glamour,fashion
beriberi,kwashiorkor
```

These aren't the only Sulphurous Words™, there are others that exist (although there are way more Fluorinated Words™ in English). Some words are Sulphurous™ and Not Sulphurous™ at the same time. Some words may or may not be considered Sulphurous™ depending on which *something* you consider the foremost. Many words are of uncertain Sulphurousness™.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sulphurous words are:

> Words with an etymology/origin from a language that starts with S (sulfur’s chemical symbol)

Details:

> pogonip - Shoshone
>  Ohio - Seneca
>  tattoo - Samoan
>  slogan - Scottish
>  mustang - Spanish
>  safari - Swahili
>  vampire - Serbian
>  soma - Sanskrit
>  glamour - Scottish
>  beriberi - Sinhalese

Many more Fluorine words exist because:

> F is the chemical symbol, and some sources estimate that as many as 45% of English words have a French origin

And of course:

> Etymology for some words is unknown, or can have multiple origins from different languages, some that start with S and others that do not

Comment: Sniped XD GJ ferret :P

Comment: so was i ;-; gg m8